# Sequelize, Postgres. Save date including UTC offset

Tags: postgresql, date, timezone, sequelize.js, utc

I have an app that creates some entities (it doesn't really matter for this question), but the entities could be created in different timezones, so I have to store UTC offset in my `createdAt` and `updatedAt` columns. For some reasons, I'm not able to save generated date correctly, please refer to the code snippet below, to get more details:

Here is what I'm doing:

```
  const { user } = userInfoWebAPICallResult as WebAPICallResult
  const now = moment(moment.now())
    .tz(user.tz!)
    .toDate();

  const entity = await Entity.create({
    ...someData,
    createdAt: now
    updatedAt: now,
  });
```

I'm getting `tz` value externally, it's a string which looks like "America/Los_Angeles". If I convert `now` to string (by calling `.format()` method) and log the received value I will see something like this "2020-01-03T16:32:53-08:00". As you can see the date has offset value, this is the correct date, but during inspecting the Database I see "2020-01-04 00:32:53.013 00", this string doesn't have offset value anymore and it looks like the resulting date was computed automatically.

I will need to implement the filtration by `createdAt` date, people from different timezone will use this filtering mechanism. I planned to expose two parameters `date` and `utcOffset` via API, which would allow me to return correct entries depending on the user time zone.

What I'm missing?

Comment: Postgres does NOT store the offset. Further storing the offset would be wrong about 1/2 time, and neither should you. It would not account for daylight saving. What you need to do is store the tz and then select date_tims AT TIME ZONE tz. Postgres will automatically adjust for daylight savings. BTW: How did you inspect the database.

Comment: @Belayer thanks for the answer. Are there any other ways to solve my issue without storing `tz` in the database?

What if I store dates as a number, by converting them in the following way:
`
const now = moment
      .utc(moment.now())
      .utcOffset(user.tz_offset)
      .unix();
`

That should give a number which already aligned with timezone

Regarding DB inspection. I just selected all rows from the table using TablePlus

Comment: You probably can do that, I wouldn't even consider it. I live by very simple database rules. One of them being dates, time stamps, etc are **always** stored as the appropriate date type. Anything else I'll assure you will later regret. Before you embark on such a complex system consider: Maintenance: What do do you do when when the currently unconsidered requirement is to generate a report for the last 6months broken down by week. And, how would you like to inherit such a design as you propose when the original developer is gone and there is insufficient or no documentation.

Comment: That entire expression where you create the `now` variable is exactly the same as just `const now = new Date();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment when the entity was created / updated should probably be stored in UTC; it is a timestamp that identifies an exact point in time when the event happened.

I would suggest dealing with time zones on the output part: convert a UTC timestamp to a display that takes the user's time zone into account.

If you need to know what time of day it was for the user who *created or updated* the entity, I would store that user's time zone in a separate column, using standard time zone identifiers (like "America/New_York" rather than "EDT" or "EST").

Comment: Seems like this is the best option. I'm not happy to have another column and I would better try to get UTC offset in already existing `createdAt` and `updatedAt` columns, but I'm not seeing that it's possible

Thanks. Will go with the separate column for the timezone